# How do I route the HTTP requests to HTTPS when the request method is not POST

Tags: http, web, https, server, alibaba-cloud

I want to route all the HTTP requests on my Alibaba cloud instance to HTTPS requests when the request method is not POST.

Here is my current configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https:// %{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

How can I change this configuration so that it only redirects when the request is not a POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST